# Hyperlinked iOS mail signature, any ideas?

Tags: ios, email, signature

I am a support technician for a school district. I've found it helpful to have links in my email signature to our helpdesk form, staff directory, HowTo documents, etc. Using meaning titles as opposed to raw URLs...  For the sake of cosistancey, I'd like to be able to have the same/similar signature on my iPad as I do in outlook.

On the iPad, i've attempted to embed HTML but after testing it all I receive in an email is the uninterpereted code, not a nice clickable link.  I've google around and looked in the app store and haven't been able to find a solution or someone saying that this isn't possible.

My last attempt a googling a found this for OSX's mail app and it gives me alittle hope that what I want may be possible.

http://allforces.com/2006/04/14/css-signatures/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have tried [**MarkdownMail**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/markdownmail-send-html-email/id390094543?mt=8)?

What you would have to do is to write your email in Markdown in the app, then paste your signature (there's a TextExpander functionality in the app so you can reuse it easily)
The app will then generate an HTML version and directly paste it into a new mail.

All you'll have to do is pick the subject, the recipient and send it.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the suits-all-cases answer you are looking for, but 99% of modern email clients auto-parse text links into clickable links. So, if you just include the links as plain text in your sig, it will work for most users.

Comment: Yes it does do this... But I don't like the ascetics of this for my users...

Comment: I think this is the only solution without jailbreaking (you have considered the jailbreak method in the link you posted above?)

Answer (score 0):

This odd workaround to paste rich text into your signature may work:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/112978/234

1. Select the rich text you want to use for your signature
2. Paste into empty signature field for account within Mail settings
3. Shake to Undo and you should see "Undo Change Attributes" prompt
4. Pasted text should now appear formatted as it was originally copied

I haven't tested it with any HTML code but it's worth a try!