# Can anyone recommend good third party iOS email clients (especially regarding signature support)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, applications, email

Can anyone recommend an iOS email client (Exchange/ActiveSync or IMAP... preferably both) that supports really sweet email signatures?  Our company email signature has an official format that has a base64 encoded image and a standardized font/color.

Please, throw me some suggestions!

Comment: This is related, but not really duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23692/hyperlinked-ios-mail-signature-any-ideas

Answer (score 2):

**[Sparrow](http://sparrowmailapp.com/)** is now available for the iPhone, and it supports IMAP.

The app description does not mention exchange, and it specifically says that there's no POP support, but being that it's such a popular mail client, I figured it's worth mentioning.

<sup>Disclaimer: I've never used it either on the Mac or on iOS</sup>

Comment: Care to explain what makes Sparrow a good client?

Comment: @ivoFlipse - hey, long time no speak. as I said in my answer, I havent used it. But, I've heard good things about it.

Comment: And what were these good things you heard? I believe you, but your answer contains no information on which I can base whether Sparrow is a good app or not.

Comment: @Ivo, I'm going to go take a mother look. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### [Moxier](http://www.moxier.com/)

This is an email client which supports Exchange ActiveSync in the AppStore. But I'm not sure it supports sweet email signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Mail is pretty good and supports signatures.  The problem I've run into is that it doesn't support saved searches (As far as I can Tell) or unread search.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, Tom! Thanks for posting answer! Can you please add a link to Outlook Mail? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try "Touchdown" for iOS, available in the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

try Mail+ for Outlook by iKonic Apps...best email client out there