# HTML/rich text email signatures in iOS?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, email, jailbreak, signature

My work (Exchange) email signature has text formatting and a photo in it, as I'm sure many do. Does anyone know of a way to enable Apple Mail like signature customization in iOS?

My iPhone is jailbroken, so if you have a jailbreak solution that works I'm good with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a JailBreak Tweak called Mail Enhancer that does exactly what you want. It's $4.99 in the BigBoss repository, and there's another one called SIGnify for $1.50 in the ModMyi repo. They both allow you to have signatures with HTML formatting, but the more expensive one has many more features that make the Mail.app much more usable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an interesting workaround for getting rich-text signatures to cooperate in iOS' mail.app (without jailbreaking):

1. Select the rich text you want to use for your signature
2. Paste into empty signature field for account within Mail settings
3. Shake to Undo and you should see "Undo Change Attributes" prompt
4. Pasted text should now appear formatted as it was originally copied

This works well in my testing within iOS7, however inline images still are not supported (they show within the signature field in settings but end up as attachments when emailed)

/via http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1522622